# I'm having trouble formatting my hardrive. How can I resolve this?

Tags: windows, format

recently I bought an SSD and cloned my entire C drive to it. My OS was still booting from my HDD, and so I figured the computer would run much better if everything was running from the SSD. Sure enough, everything works great. I'm ready to format and wipe the old HDD, but every time I try to do it I get this error:
**You cannot format this volume.**
*It contains the version of windows you are using.*

The C drive does indeed show the little blue windows icon next to it under the "This PC" section. What's weird is I'm pretty sure I'm not booting windows from the C drive anymore. I made sure of that in Bios. Heck, just by performance alone it's obvious.
How the heck can I format my C drive? I'm at a loss as to what to do.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently used the same license which explains the issue.

Put the drive in a different computer and format it on the other computer. That will work.

I assume your computer starts completely properly when the hard drive has been disconnected. You need to disconnect the drive to ensure the system starts normally.

Comment: Yep, it does. Okay, I'll try that! Thank you.

Comment: Did you try the drive in another computer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
If you have a USB with a Windows 10 installation tool
Boot to it and then wipe the HDD

One thing I should recommend in my experience is that cloned HDD to SSD tend to have issues sometimes loading programs or even booting to windows itself

It'll be better if you do a fresh install of windows 10 on your SSD and then copy your files from the HDD

Hope it helps !